# Альтернативы SourceTrail?

Tags: c++, архитектура, проектирование, поиск-программ, uml

SourceTrail приложение которое показывает связь между сущности в коде в виде графа, помогая разобраться в коде. С определенного момента его поддержка закончилась.
Интересует есть его альтернативы в виде standalone приложения или в качестве расширения к vscode?